# Getting the number of all elements in collection from PagedList(Web API) with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to figure out how to get the number of all elements in collection from server to pass this number to `total-items`, so that I could navigate between all of the data, not only the first page of elements.

My AngularJS controller's code -

```
    $scope.gamesPerPage = 5;    
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.totalGames = 0;
    getResultsPage($scope.currentPage, $scope.gamesPerPage);

    $scope.pageChanged = function (pageNumber, pageSize) {
        getResultsPage(pageNumber, pageSize);
    };   

    function getResultsPage(pageNumber, pageSize) {
        gamesFactory.getGames(pageNumber, pageSize)
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.games = response;
            $scope.totalGames = response.Count; //Returns the number of PagedList elements, 5 in my case
        })        
    };
```

Factory service -

```
    var urlBase = '/api/games/'; 
    factory.getGames = function (pageNumber, pageSize) {
        return $http.get(urlBase + pageNumber + '/' + pageSize);
    };
```

And Web APi 2, Get method -

```
        [Route("api/games/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}")]
        public IQueryable<Game> GetGames(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {            
            List<Game> games = db.Games.ToList();
            PagedList<Game> pagedList = new PagedList<Game>(games, pageNumber, pageSize);
            return pagedList.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your response into an object which will hold total count of games and paged collection of games.

You could do something like this:

```
public class GamesHolder
{
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Game> PagedGames { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore, your API enpoint should return:

```
[Route("api/games/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}")]
public GamesHolder GetGames(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{            
    List<Game> games = db.Games.ToList();
    return new GamesHolder()
    {
       TotalCount = games.Count,
       PagedGames = new PagedList<Game>(games, pageNumber, pageSize)
    }
}
```

Furthermore, inside your Angular `getResultsPage` function you will be able to retrieve an object:

```
function getResultsPage(pageNumber, pageSize) {
    gamesFactory.getGames(pageNumber, pageSize)
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.games = response.pagedGames;
        $scope.totalGames = response.totalCount;
    })        
};
```